# Cannot read property 'code' of undefined, Decoding Firebase ID token failed

Tags: node.js, firebase, react-native, firebase-authentication, react-native-firebase

I intermittently get this error on about 5% of requests, and I am not sure why. It seems to work most of the time, but I'd like to get it to 100%.

```
{"name":"myapp","hostname":"worker-844ddfbc9f-ntlmz","pid":18,"level":50,
"err":"[Throws: Cannot read property 'code' of undefined]",
"msg":"Context creation failed: Decoding Firebase ID token failed. Make sure you passed the entire string JWT which represents an ID token. See https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/verify-id-tokens for details on how to retrieve an ID token.",
"time":"2020-02-12T02:16:33.538Z","v":0}
TypeError: Cannot read property 'code' of undefined
    at FirebaseAuthError.get [as code] (/app/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/utils/error.js:51:35)
    at FirebaseAuthError.FirebaseError.toJSON (/app/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/utils/error.js:67:24)
    at JSON.stringify (<anonymous>)
    at prettyJSONStringify (/app/node_modules/apollo-server-core/dist/runHttpQuery.js:257:17)
    at throwHttpGraphQLError (/app/node_modules/apollo-server-core/dist/runHttpQuery.js:26:42)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/apollo-server-core/dist/runHttpQuery.js:66:28)
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at fulfilled (/app/node_modules/apollo-server-core/dist/runHttpQuery.js:4:58)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
```

**client**

```
const authLink = setContext(async (_, { headers }) => {
    let token;
    if (firebase.auth().currentUser) {
        token = await firebase.auth().currentUser.getIdToken();
    }
    return {
        headers: {
            ...headers,
            authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
        },
    };
});
```

**server**

```
            let token = req.headers.authorization;

            if (!token || !token.length) {
                console.log('no token');
            }

            token = token.split('Bearer ')[1];

            // validate JWT and pluck user id
            const { uid } = await firebase.auth().verifyIdToken(token);

            // find the user based on id
            const user = await firebase.auth().getUser(uid);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your client code will result an authorization header of `Bearer undefined` if the `firebase.auth().currentUser` is falsey.  This authorization header will not cause `no token` to be logged in the server code (its length is 16).  The server code will then fail when running `firebase.auth().verifyIdToken('undefined')`.

You need to either prevent the client from sending the request if `firebase.auth().currentUser` is falsey or catch the undefined token in the server code.

Note: using an undefined variable in a template string results in the string 'undefined' (not an empty string).